# BFS modification

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

Im trying to find all shortest path, where all paths have value 1. 
I used modified BFS. I was adding closed nodes into queue too. When I find the end node I stop adding nodes and just count the end node in the queue. But it doesn't work for my testing input. Why is my idea bad?

pseudocode

```
addIntoQueue(startNode)
while(!queueIsEmpty()){
   nodeMain = dequeue()
   if(nodeMain==stopNode){
      found=true
      count++
   }
   if(!found)
   for(all node in NodeNeighbors){
      if(node!=CLOSED){
         addToQueue(node)
      }
   }
   nodeMain=CLOSED
}
```

Comment: what is count++ doing? You haven't used that variable anywhere else in your code. Also you might want to consider breaking out of the loop early seeing as after you find the `stopNode`, no more nodes are added to the queue

Comment: no I want to count all the shortest ways. so count is counting it.

Comment: I can't post the code. I came just ask about the idea of adding OPEN nodes into queue. @Al Kepp

Comment: Paths can overlap. I don't see how your code accounts for that.

Comment: There can be just one path in one direction.

Comment: That's not true; take V = {A,B,C,D,E}, A as source node, E as target node, and edges (A,B), (A,C), (C,D), (B,D), (D,E). The two paths A-C-D-E and A-B-D-E overlap, and their overlap is the edge (D,E).

Comment: But in my problem can't overlap.

Comment: Then the problem probably is that you set found to true once you find a single path; after that, the queue will be emptied and no further paths can be considered.

Comment: But when I found the endNode, all paths which can possibly go to the endNode are already in queue, i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some issues in your code:

1. **Infinite loop**: In case of no path from source to target - but there is a cycle in the graph, your algorithm should return `0` - however, it is stuck in an infinite loop instead.
2. **Counting wrong paths:** Let's assume the `target` is at depth `4` from the `source`, and is reached by the path `source->v1->v2->target`. Now, assume you also have a path `source->v3->v4->v5->target` in your graph, and for some reason `v4` was inserted to the queue before `target` (it can happen, there is no restriction on the orderings among these 2). You would also add `target` again to the queue for the edge `(v5,target)`, and also count the path `source->v3->v4->v5->target`, but this is not a shortest path - but you did count it...

Have a look on this graph for example:
[image]

In the above, you first start from `s`, and add all its neighbors to the queue. Now, let's assume `v2` is added before `v1` (that can happen, nothing prevents it..)

Now, at the next step, `v2` will be expanded and you will add `v3` to the queue.

Next, `v1` is processed and `target` is added to the queue.

Now, `v3` is processed and add `target` to the queue again.

Now, `target` is processed, `count` is increased, and the flag `found` is set.

The queue is not empty yet, you now process `target` - and increase `count` again.

As a result, when done - `count == 2`, but there is only 1 shortest path. This happens because you also counted the path `s->v2->v3->t`.

Comment: 1) My graph is coherent. 2)If there is path source->v4->v5->target and source->v1->v2->target I should  count 2 ways.

Comment: @SpeedEX505 The example is one path of length 4 and one path of length 5. Only the first one should be counted- you (might) count both.

Comment: I have problem I count more path then there are actually

Comment: BFS cant insert into queue depth+1 when there are not all nodes of depth inserted. I dont understand your exmaple

Comment: @SpeedEX505 Look at the edit, I explained it with more details. The problem is, this behavior makes you count some paths of length `d+1` (where `d` is the shortest path length).